# Facing an error while creating ML Workspace through Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I am trying to build a Machine Learning pipeline on Azure DevOps. I followed this tutorial: https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/aml/#author-praneet-singh-solanki

However, in Exercise 1- Step 3: Create or get workspace, I'm facing an error while authorising my Azure Subscription.

"Error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. Ensure that the user has permissions to create an Azure Active Directory Application."

[Here is a snapshot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6pfM.png) Also, my subscription is free tier as of now. Could that be a reason?

Answer (score 1):

> My subscription is free tier as of now. Could that be a reason?

No, you don't need worry about this. For free credit, we offered $200 free quota, and also the use will not be limited(just limit use depth only).

> "Error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. Ensure that
>   the user has permissions to create an Azure Active Directory
>   Application."

This issue should caused by your incorrect role setting. Even you are owner of AAD or application, if you did not assign the role of **Application administrator**, you still will receive the error of permission not enough.

Please assign the role of your AD application to a Administrator permission. Go Azure Portal -> Azure Active directory-> Users, and then search your account which you will used in Azure Devops pipeline, and then follow the below setting to assign the role.

[image]

Then back to Azure Devops, refresh the Azure Subscription and Authorized again.